# Nhibernate Criteria: Use of Expression.in()

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

What is the use of Expression.In() in nhibernate and What would be the equivalent sql query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It produces a [SQL "IN" statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

For example:

```
var idArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo))
    .Add(Expression.In("Id", idArray)
    .List<Foo>();
```

Would produce sql equivalent to:

```
select * from Foo where Foo.Id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```